# "Blocked or could not reach STUN server" : Error is coming while testing STUN server

Tags: stun, turn

Currently I am referring below link for installing STUN server in Ubuntu:

https://antonraharja.com/2016/03/17/setting-up-stunturn-server-on-meetme-id/

From that Installation and Basic Configurations(Part 1&2) steps I had completed and they are working properly. But in Part-3, **sudo apt-get install stun** is working, but next when I tried **stun meetme.id** command then it is not working and I am getting below error :

STUN client version 0.96
Primary : Blocked or could not reach STUN server
Return value is : 0x00001c

So, can anyone tell me how resolve this or provide me any suggested link?

Comment: The servers on meetme.id appears to be down. (I tested several combinations).  You can test stun client connectivity against `stun.stunprotocol.org`.  Shameless plug: Use my code [here](http://www.stunprotocol.org/).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install stuntman-server` and `sudo apt-get install stuntman-client`